# The relation $x\sim y$ iff $S(x)=S(y)$ for $S(x)=\{z\in G:\langle x,z\rangle=G\}$ for a finite, non-cyclic group $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Set $G$ a finite 2-generated group (not cyclic) and if $x\in G$, call $S(x)=\{z\in G: \langle x,z \rangle =G \}$. Define on the elements of $G -\{e\}$ this equivalence relation:
$x \sim y$ if and only if $S(x)=S(y)$.

> Are there examples of group with $|[x]|>1$ for every $x\in G$, except the identity?
>
> The dihedral group $D_p$ ($p$ prime) is an example, are there many others?

Comment: Use `$\sim$` for $\sim$.

Comment: When $G=D_3$, $S(e)=\emptyset$ while for all non-identity $g\in G$, $S(g)\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: This works for any two-generated group of odd order. (Every element generates a cyclic subgroup with a non-trivial automorphism, so this subgroup has more than one generator, and any two generators of this cyclic subgroup are related.)

Comment: (That is, if $G$ is a two-generated group of odd order then either $S(g)$ is empty or $[g]$ contains at least two elements. So I guess the non-cyclic groups of order $pq$ work, with $p, q$ non-equal primes bigger than $2$?)

Comment: Every group which has no generating set of two elements satisfies this (because $S(x) = \emptyset$ for all $x$, so that $x\sim y$ for all $x,y$)